# Store data in a DTO from servlet ...?

Tags: java, servlets, dto, getter-setter

Can the below way be implemented to store data in a DTO and access it from any where in the application rather than going for a context ?

Please provide suggestions !!!

```
public class DummyDTO {
    private String name = null;
    private String age = null;

    // getters and setters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class MyServletClass extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        DummyDTO dummyDTO = new DummyDTO();
        dummyDTO.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
        dummyDTO.setAge(request.getParameter("age"));
        AnotherClass.setValues(dummyDTO);
    }

    public class AnotherClass {
        String name = "";
        String age = "";

        public static void setValues(DummyDTO dummyDTO) {
            name = dummyDTO.getName();
            age = dummyDTO.getAge();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't. Static fields are global to the whole ClassLoader, (to the whole). So if you have several concurrent requests to your servlet, the second one will overwrite the data stored by the first one in the static fields (and in a thread-unsafe way, additionnally).

If the data is local to a request, you should store it in a request attribute. That's what they're for.

Side note: your fields are not static, but the only way your code would compile is to make them static.

Comment: what if method `setValues` is not static?

Comment: If the method is not static, you need to instantiate the class to be able to call the method: (`new AnotherClass()`), so you need to store the object somewhere to access it from everywhere, and you're back to your original problem.

Comment: One more doubt Nizet...Can we make the static method synchronized..like the following pieve of code -----              synchronized(AnotherClass.class) { }...or any other way like ...............public static synchronized void setValues(DummyDTO dummyDTO) {             name = dummyDTO.getName();             age = dummyDTO.getAge();         }

Comment: That would make it thread-safe, but still incorrect: there is only one name in memory, but several concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this....

Put values in a map which has key the user's sessionId.

```
public class MyServletClass extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    DummyDTO dummyDTO = new DummyDTO();
    dummyDTO.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
    dummyDTO.setAge(request.getParameter("age"));
    AnotherClass.setValues(dummyDTO, request.getSession().getSessionId());
}

public class AnotherClass {
    String name = "";
    String age = "";

    private static HashMap<String, DummyDTO> map; 
    public static HashMap<String, DummyDTO> setValues(DummyDTO dummyDTO, String key) {
      return map.put(key, dummyDTO);
    }
}
```

}